# Deserializing xmla file to an object using Analysis Management Objects (AMO)

Tags: c#, ssas

I want to deserialize an xmla file which has a database object in it to the correct object representation of it. (I don't know if it is supposed to be a Database). So, I do the following:

```
Database db = new Database();
XmlTextReader xmlread = new XmlTextReader("input.xmla");
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Utils.Deserialize(xmlread, db);
xmlread.Close();
```

But I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlSerializationException: Unexpected root 'Create' (namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine') when trying to read 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Database'.
  at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.DesignXmlReader.ReadRoot (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.DesignXmlReader.DeserializeComponent (IDesignerSerializationManager manager, System.Xml.XmlReader reader, System.Type root) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.JaXmlSerializer.DeserializeComponent (IDesignerSerializationManager manager, System.Xml.XmlReader reader, System.Type root) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Utils.Deserialize (System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader, Microsoft.AnalysisServices.MajorObject obj) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

The input.xmla file looks like this:

```
<Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <ObjectDefinition>
         <Database xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200">
             <ID>100</ID>
             <Name>Deserialized</Name>
             <Description>Deserialized Description</Description>
        </Database>
    </ObjectDefinition>
</Create>
```

I couldn't find a good example for it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider the xml namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine`

Comment: @L.B, I am very unexperienced with c#, amo and deserialization, can you explain more please?

Comment: Sorry Faruk, I've never worked with `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Utils` But there should be some way to set the namespace in the library. Maybe you can use `xmlread.NameTable.Add`

Comment: I tried `xmlread.NameTable.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine");` it didn't work, still the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you are trying to deserialize a xmla-document containing a "CREATE"-command, and not only the serialized database-object. If you had a xml-reader sitting only on the database-node, it should work!

Comment: Yes, that was right and also I had to move the   `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine"` namespace to the database node on xmla file. Is it possible to add this programatically omitting at the xmla file?